# Removing Check on Radio Button jQuery

Tags: jquery, radio-button, checked

I am using:

> var choice;
>
> $('a.enter').click(function() {
>
> choice = $('input:checked').val();
>
> });

To determine choice for a radio button being checked.

Then, when running an event like:

> $('a.exit').click(function() {
>
> $('input').prop('checked', false);
>
> });

I clear out the check.. Then when I run the first event again, instead of choice equaling the value of the checked radio button, it returns "undefined"

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I may not be totally clear on the process you're describing, but if I understand correctly, when you:

> run the first event again

`$('input:checked').val();` will return 'undefined' since there are no checked inputs - you just unchecked them all with `$('input').prop('checked', false);`.

What result are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a.enter').click(function() {

choice = $('input:checked').val();

});
```

**choise** is not a GLOBAL variable here.

Make some demo and show the url. Or a simple jsfiddle, please.

EDIT:

It seems I intentionally skipped the top declaration to let some users make polemic comments.

Actually it doesn't matter you declare it or not.

When the second time you click **a.enter**, there is no checked inputs, and no value is assigned to your variable.

Use this code

http://jsfiddle.net/ZE2Pb/

Answer (score 0):

After you clicked on `a.exit` $('input:checked') return jQuery object without elements.
`.val()` for jQuery object without elements always return `undefined` because can't find property `value`